# Instagram feed no longer displaying images on website

Tags: wordpress, instagram-api

I'm not a tech person so forgive me - until today my website was developed to display a selection of instagram images on my (bluehosted) website based on various hashtags, but now the images no longer display. The url is http://go-where.co.uk

The original developer has moved on and I am in need of advice to resolve the issue please as the website relies on this functionality. I have notes left by the previous developer which contain links that cannot be posted as I am a new user and have a limit of 2 links.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to take a look at the issue... there is something wrong with your wordpress config as the urls over at instagram have not been altered...

[this photo that I pulled from your site still renders just fine](https://www.instagram.com/p/BCQI4EGwhT4/)

your code looks something like

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BCQI4EGwhT4/">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/instagram/12748323_236400550029515_122771_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTE5MzQ5MjkzODMyNDMxNzQzMg%3D%3D.2">
</a>
```

This issue is therefore with your `<img>` tag and has nothing to do with the Instagram API.